# How to show latest release's Git tag with message

Tags: upgrade, git, repository, github

Was creating a script to update a Github application in-place and needed to ***print changes made in the latest Git tagged release*** so users could make an informed decision about pulling the trigger on the update before altering a working production environment.  ***A requirement was that I needed to alias the last tag*** because I wanted to automate as much as possible without having to change the tag that prints every release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your own solution appears to require that the checked out head match the tag you’re interested in, the following works without a separate `git describe`:

```
git tag -l -n10 --points-at HEAD
```

Comment: Outstanding: the most elegant solution is the one that strips out undue complexity.  Yours accomplishes the task with a single command.  Looks like yours is the only other way of achieving the desired outcome.  Thanks bud-

Answer (score 0):

To print the last annotated Git tag with 10 lines of the tag's comments:

```
git tag -l -n10 $(git describe)
```

If anybody has a pure Git solution that can achieve the same result- *including aliasing the tag so it doesn't require constant changing in the script-* with a ***single git command*** (mine uses two), please share-